# ignore a folder in any git project?

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gitignore, rider

So where I work we use a variety of IDEs. I'm the only one that is using Rider so I don't want to add it to the project `.gitignore` file. Rider creates a `.run` folder in the root of every project. I want to tell git to ignore this folder in all projects. I added a local `~/.gitignore` with the following content:

```
.run/
```

Yet i'm still seeing the `.run` in `git status`. The `.run` folder is untracked:
[image]

Comment: You could have a look at [`git config [--global] core.excludesFile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreexcludesFile). As per the linked documentation, you might be able to set a "global" gitignore in `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`.

Comment: Are you sure the `.gitignore` is in the proper directory? I tried doing this locally and `.gitignore` seems to pick it up

Comment: The *default* location for your personal global `.gitignore` depends on your Git build, but if you set your personal global `core.excludesFile` (as @TorgeRosendahl suggested) you can pick a known path instead of relying on any one particular build.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing git cache

- add `/<path_to_folder>/.run` in gitignore file
- `git rm -rf --cached .`
- `git add`

Now the magic will happen and your .run folder will be ignored

Comment: I believe this is only for `tracked` files. This was `untracked` files so that wouldn't have worked.

Comment: if we've added the folder in gitignore it'll not show up in untracked as well

Comment: yes but you don't need to do `git rm --rf --cached .` unless its tracked.

Answer (score 0):

So the comment from @TorgeRosendahl got me headed in the right direction. I looked in my global git settings and found the following:
`core.excludefile=/mnt/c/Users/<user>/.gitignore_global`

I didn't remember even setting that but apparently i did it a long time ago so git under windows & wsl could share the same `.gitignore` file. I tried to change `.gitignore_global` didn't work until I looked more closely at my config setting above i'm missing the `s` in core.exclude**s**files. After I fixed that it started working.